# Creating a file with some content in Shell scripting

Tags: bash

I'm a little new to Shell Scripting and I want to create a new file inside the script and want to add content and then close it. It should not take the arguments from the user. Everything from the path and content is predefined. How can I do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just use output redirection. E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "some file content" > /path/to/outputfile
```

The `>` will write all `stdin` provided by the `stdout` of `echo` to the file `outputfile` here.

Alternatively, you could also use `tee` and a pipe for this. E.g.

```
echo "some file content" | tee outputfile
```

*Be aware that any of the examples will overwrite an existing `outputfile`.*

If you need to **append** to a currently existing file, use `>>` instead of `>` or `tee -a`.

If you don't accept user input in this line, no user input can change the behaviour here.

Comment: For people who want to have a line breaker inside their file, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9741470/10512595

Answer (score 24):

I think it is superior to use a [here doc](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings) to create a new file in a script. It is cleaner looking, which I believe encourages readability.

For example:

```
cat > filename <<- "EOF"
file contents
more contents
EOF
```

The `"-"` in `<<-` is optional, allowing for tabbed indents which will be [stripped](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) when the file is created. The quotes around the `"EOF"` prevent the "here doc" from doing any substitutions.