# How to write a script that generates a text file and opens it?

Tags: bash, scripts, window-manager, window

I have recently started using Linux and I want to create a script that will do the following:

1. Generate a text file where the first line is: Work Plan {todays date}
2. Save it with the name work_plan_{todays date}
3. (Optional - not essential like points 1 and 2) Open it full screen height, half screen width.

How can I write a script that will do this and that I can call from any terminal without having to out its full path? That is, I want to just type, for example, gen-work-plan and not /usr/home/document/gen-work-plan...

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: This might have already been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/319910/creating-a-file-with-some-content-in-shell-scripting I hope it helps. Maybe you should ask something more specific.

Comment: Well I did make an effort and I have created scripts to launch things like the settings panel. But I don't know how to do something as elaborate as generating a text file with a certain name and text already inside it. Also being able to run it from any terminal without its full path is something I want to also use for my existing scripts like the one for the settings panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To do exactly what you describe takes a script

[image]

[image]

Couldn't resist posting an answer...

To create a file, with the current date as a title and as header inside would take one or two lines. However, if you want to:

- prevent the file to be overwritten if you run the command accidentally
- open the file with gedit
- wait for the window to appear and subsequently move and resize it

...it will take a few lines more than that.

The script below will:

- create a new file, in an arbitrary directory, named after the current date, ***only*** if it doesn't exist yet. You wouldn't want to overwrite it.
- add the current date to the file, like:

  ```
  Workplan 12-12-12
  ```
- open the file with `gedit`, wait for the window to appear (!), move the window to the upper left, resize it to 50% (width), 100% (height)

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import subprocess
import os
import time
# --- add the absolute path to the directory where you'd like to store the Workplans
filedir = "/home/jacob"
# ---
curr = "Workplan "+time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"); out = curr+".txt"
file = os.path.join(filedir, out)
# check for the file to exist (you wouldn't overwrite it)
if not os.path.exists(file):
    # write "Workplan" + date to the file
    open(file, "wt").write(curr)
    # open the file with gedit
    subprocess.Popen(["gedit", file])
    # wait for the window to appear, move/resize it
    t = 0
    while t < 20:
        t += 1; time.sleep(1)
        wlist = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-l"]).decode("utf-8")
        if out in wlist:
            w = [l.split()[0] for l in wlist.splitlines() if out in l][0]
            for cmd in [["xdotool", "windowmove", w, "0", "0"],
                        ["xdotool", "windowsize", w, "47%", "100%"]]:
                subprocess.call(cmd)
            break
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs both `xdotool` and `wmctrl`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `workplan` (no extension!) in `~/bin`. Create `~/bin` if it does not exist yet. ***Make the script executable***.
3. In the head of the script, set the (absolute!) path to where you'd lioke to store your work plans:

   ```
   # --- set the abs. path to where you'd like to store the "Workplans"
   filedir = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad"
   # ---
   ```
4. Log out ands back in, run the command simply by:

   ```
   workplan
   ```

#### Explanation

- To create a file in python, we can simply use:

  ```
  open("file", "wt").write("sometext")
  ```
- for the *moving* and *resizing* however, we need to wait for the window to appear by checking if the window appears in the output of the command:

  ```
  wmctrl -l
  ```

  in the script:

  ```py
      while t < 20:
          t += 1; time.sleep(1)
          wlist = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-l"]).decode("utf-8")
          if out in wlist:
  ```
- Then once the window came into existence, we split off the window id (first string in the lines in the output of `wmctrl -l`), move the window to the top left, and resize it:

  ```py
              w = [l.split()[0] for l in wlist.splitlines() if curr in l][0]
              for cmd in [["xdotool", "windowmove", w, "0", "0"],
                          ["xdotool", "windowsize", w, "47%", "100%"]]:
                  subprocess.call(cmd)
              break
  ```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
echo "Work Plan $today" > work_plan_"$today"
gedit work_plan_"$today"
```

Don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x gen-work-plan`.

To run it without path, either add the directory containing the scrip to your `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc` (recommended for security):

```
export PATH=$PATH:_Location_of_the_file_
```

Or symlink it in `/usr/bin`:

```
ln -s _location_/gen-work-plan /usr/bin/gen-work-plan
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple bash script I would use

```
#!/bin/bash
dat=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
touch work_plan_$dat
echo "Work Plan $dat" > work_plan_$dat
if [ -f work_plan_$dat ]; then
    echo "Successfully created file work_plan_$dat"
fi
gedit work_plan_$dat
```

To run this script without its path, its location should be included in `$PATH` environment variable. You can do it with this line

```
PATH=/an/example/path:"$PATH"
```

You may want to add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file

**OR**

You may create a symbolic link with this command

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/your/file /usr/local/bin/name_of_new_command
```

after that make sure the file is executable, if necessary, run the following command

```
chmod +x /full/path/to/your/file
```

credits to c0rp for this answer https://askubuntu.com/users/164083/c0rp

Source, see the link below

[How to run scripts without typing the full path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-to-run-scripts-without-typing-the-full-path)

Comment: You forgot to open the file with Gedit. And instead of adding a location to PATH, rather put the script in an already recognized location like `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: That's true, added some improvements