# Using EOF for Templating a bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, apache2, templates

I am attempting to create a simple script which will generate files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory using a for loop, and get it to do this using a template within my script. This is what the snippet of my script looks like:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apache2/sites-available/${VHOST}.com.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ${VHOST}.com
ServerAlias www.${VHOST}.com
ServerAdmin xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/${VHOST}.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${VHOST}_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${VHOST}_access.log combined
Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

NOTE: ${VHOST} is simply a value specified within my for loop.

The result which I am trying to achieve is that the template output will be sent to a file `${VHOST}.com.conf` within the sites-available directory.

My above snippet does not work and I receive the following errors:

```
./vhost.sh: line 21: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./vhost.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./vhost.sh: line 21: `<<-EOF <VirtualHost *:80>'
```

**UPDATE:**

I followed @PerlDuck's suggestion by updating the file as follows

```
cat > /etc/apache2/sites-available/${VHOST}.com.conf <<-EOF
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ${VHOST}.com
ServerAlias www.${VHOST}.com
ServerAdmin hunter@prepaidmeters.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/${VHOST}.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${VHOST}_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${VHOST}_access.log combined
Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

Attempting `cat > /etc/apache2/sites-available/${VHOST}.com.conf <<- "EOF"` also did not work. Both produce the same error.

```
./vhost.sh: line 22: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./vhost.sh: line 23: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/806750/504066. You need `cat > ${VHOST}.com.conf <<EOF...EOF`

Comment: This does not produce the desired outcome. Will update my question

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about the "must not" comment I wrote a minute ago. **But** you have an extra space after the last `END `. That's the error.

Comment: _Heredocs_ (that's their name) are peculiar. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PerlDuck resolved my issue for me. This is simply a case of unwanted blank space. This extra whitespace after the final EOF prevents the heredoc from terminating. Thus producing the error

```
./vhost.sh: line 22: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./vhost.sh: line 23: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Remember kids! Blankspace, blankspace, blankspace !