# How to write an arg into a file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to write some content to a file and at the same time change some values that will be passed through the args.

I followed this answer 
[Creating a file with some content in Shell scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319910/creating-a-file-with-some-content-in-shell-scripting#319913)

```
cat > filename <<- "EOF"
File contents
More contents
EOF
```

So let say when I run the script like this:

```
./script Abraham
```

and I want to write inside the file something like:

```
Hello Abraham
More contents, etc...
```

I came from a Javascript background so I was trying something like:

```
`Hello ${1}, etc...`
```

but what I was getting inside the file was:

```
Hello $1
More contents, etc...
```

because is not letting me set the variable of the argument. So how can I accomplish that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes around the initial `"EOF"` prevent variable expansion. To use variables in the heredoc text, you need to an unquoted delimiter:

```
cat > filename <<- EOF
Hello $1
More contents, etc...
EOF
```

But then you'll have to be careful about shell syntax in the rest of the contents.

Another option is to write this line separately, and write the fixed contents using a heredoc:

```
echo "Hello $1" > filename
cat >> filename <<- "EOF"
More contents, etc...
EOF
```

Note the use of `>>` for appending after the initial write.